# Correct way of building variable length argument line to external command in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, arguments

I need to use "find" command to find several different sets of files in my Bash function, depending on my script input.

So, I have thing like:

```
DAYS=30
case $1 in
A1) ARGLINE="-name 'FOO*.xml' -or -name 'BAR*.xml' -or -name 'BTT*.txt'"
    ;;
A2) ARGLINE="-name 'PO*xml' -or -name 'PR*xml'"
    ;;
...
esac
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +${DAYS} `${ARGLINE}`
```

**This works.**

However, as soon as I want to use variable for number of days to search back to, like this:

```
DAYS=30
case $1 in
A1) ARGLINE="-name 'FOO*.xml' -or -name 'BAR*.xml' -or -name 'BTT*.txt'"
    ;;
A2) ARGLINE="-name 'PO*xml' -or -name 'PR*xml'"
    ;;
...
esac
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
    DAYS=$2
fi
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +${DAYS} `${ARGLINE}`
```

The function fails when *find* doesn't find any files matching, with the following error:

> No command '-name' found, did you mean:  Command 'uname' from package
>   'coreutils' (main)
>   -name: command not found

It however works correctly, when the number of days is such that find finds some files.
It also fails when I try to pipe the output of succesful run into another command.

How should I correctly build the argument line for "find"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bash`, use an array:

```
args=( '(' -name 'FOO*.xml' -or -name 'BAR*.xml' -or -name 'BTT*.txt' ')' )
```

The extra parentheses are there for creating the correct boolean logical grouping since you use `-or`).

Then, in the `find` command:

```
find ...some arguments... "${args[@]}"
```

You have an additional issue in that you use

```
`$ARGLINE`
```

This is a command substitution, similar to `$( $ARGLINE )` and the shell will try to execute `$ARGLINE` (its value) as a command.  This is why you get "No command '-name' found".  The command substitution fails, but the `find` runs, which is why you think it "works".

Comment: Thank you, but if I do this, then no errors, but find appears to ignore DAYS parameter and always gives *all* files in the directory matching params set in $ARGLINE

Comment: @Gnudiff Ah. I see why. Your arguments regarding `-name` has to be in parentheses:  `args=( '(' -name ... -or -name ... etc. ')' )`

Comment: @Gnudiff See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you; I solved this by passing the DAYS argument to the ARGLINE via ARGLINE+=(-mtime +${DAYS}) . It is not clear to me though, why the original line didn't work and why would I need to have extra parenthesis.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, putting DAYS into ARGLINE didn't help. Going to try with parenthesis as you suggested.

Comment: @Gnudiff, you want the `-mtime` to apply to all the `-name`s, but `-mtime +2 -name foo -or -name bar` is parsed as `(-mtime +2 -name foo ) -or -name bar`. There's an implicit _and_ between adjacent conditions, and _and_ has higher priority than _or_. So you need to put the parenthesis there manually: `-mtime +2 ( -name foo -or -name bar )`

Comment: @Gnudiff If you want to put the `-mtime` argument into the array, you will have to use `args=( -mtime +"$DAYS" '(' ... ')' )` where `...` are the `-name` tests.

Comment: @ilkkachu Unless they put the `-mtime` in the array...

Comment: @Kusalananda Yeah, the main thing is that the resulting command line has them in the right place.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here, is that quotes don't work inside quotes: after expanding a variable, the quotes inside it are just ordinary characters, e.g.:

```
$ foo='foo "bar doo"'
$ printf "<%s>\n" $foo
<foo>
<"bar>
<doo">
```

You should use an array to store command arguments like that:

```
ARGS=(-name 'FOO*.xml' -or -name 'BAR*.xml' -or -name 'BTT*.txt')
```

The shell will process quoting at this stage, and store distinct shell words as distinct array elements. Use the array like this:

```
find . "${ARGLINE[@]}"
```

If you want or need to, you can build the array piece by piece, this should result in the same array:

```
ARGS=(-name 'FOO*.xml')
ARGS+=(-or -name 'BAR*.xml')
ARGS+=(-or -name 'BTT*.txt')
```

---

However, note that you also used backticks to "quote" `${ARGLINE}`. That will start a command substitution and run the contents of `ARGLINE` as a command. That's where your error comes from, the shell tries to run a program called `-name`.

---

Actually, in your example, you don't *need* an array, since you don't have any whitespace within the arguments. The main issue here usually is that the difference between whitespace *between* the arguments, and the whitespace *within* the arguments gets lost when the command line is stored to a string. But in your case, this might work, not that I'd recommend it:

```
set -f       # disable globbing
ARGLINE="-name FOO*.xml -or -name BAR*.xml -or -name BTT*.txt"
find . $ARGLINE
```

Comment: These are both very good answers, Kusalalanda was first, but I feel that the reference to array addition and building argument line one by one is a bit more complete.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the problem is not with whitespace, but with characters of `$IFS` (which so happen to be SPC, TAB and NL, 3 whitespace characters *by default*). If the argument contained whitespace, you could still use split+glob, but using a different separator in `$IFS` (again, not recommended where you can use arrays instead).